# How to run bash commands in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 12.04, bash, command-line

before in Ubuntu 12.04 when I make simple bash commands, it works but in Ubuntu 13.10 I can only open it with gedit! How I can run it by only one click?

Comment: Use. Desktop. Files.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: see e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/378071/stop-py-opening-in-gedit

Answer (score 4):

Open the file manager, go to the `Files` menu and select `Preferences` to open the "Preferences" dialog.

In the `Behaviour` tab activate the option `Run executable text files when they are opened` in the `Exexcutable Text Files` section:

[image]

Note that this may cause you to run potential harmful code instead of opening it in a text editor. So it's usually better to activate `Ask each time` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Open your editor , for example gedit and paste this lines.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/alex/Documents/exec.sh
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

save this file with `somename.desktop`

Description of those lines :

- **Version** is the version of this .desktop file.
- **Name** is the name of the application, like 'VLC media player'.
- **Comment** is a phrase or two describing what this program does, like 'Plays your music and videos files'.
- **Exec** is the path to the executable file. The full path to the executable file must be used only in case it isn't in any of the paths specified in the $PATH variable. For example, any files that are inside the path /usr/bin don't need to have their full path specified in the Exec field, but only their filename. To see all the paths in the $PATH variable you can open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T and type in

  echo $PATH
- **Icon field** is the icon that should be used by the launcher and represents the application. All icons that are under the directory /usr/share/pixmaps don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension. For example, if the icon file is /usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png, then the Icon field should be just 'wallch'. All other icons should have their full path specified.
- **Terminal field** specifies whether the application should run in a terminal window or not.
- **Type field** specifies the type of the launcher file. The type can be Application, Link or Directory, but this article covers the 'Application' type.
- **Categories field** specifies the category of the application. It is used by the Dash so as to categorize the applications. A launcher being a 'Utility;Application;' should be under the 'Accessories' section etc.

[Source here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)